# Can't boot Windows 10 through SSD, can through USB

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootable-media

Just bought a new SSD and installed Win10 on a part of it. Previously on this PC I had a SSD with Win7/Ubuntu 14.04 and had some boot problems too.

The problem I have is that when I boot it normally from the SSD, I get a an error saying "No such device" followed by a long number.

The strange thing is that when I choose to boot from the USB, it says to press any key to boot from the USB and if I don't, it starts the Win10 and I can normally work on it.

The boot fixer from the Win10 installer doesn't help. I'm having trouble making a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 USB. Not sure if it's relevant, but the motherboard is an Asrock p55 Deluxe3. Maybe I should update it's BIOS?

If I connect the old SSD, it boots and works just fine.

How do I fix this? What more information can I provide to fix this?

Comment: I would copy the old drive to the new drive through something like carbon copy to rule out drive issues.  Sometimes the controller the lets you boot the hard drive through USB has special configuration.

Comment: I would first go into the bios and check the boot order to make sure that its setup correctly, given that you can't boot through the SSD, I assume you try to run the installer, but it doesn't work. When the boot order is corrected, you should now be able to install windows to the new SSD. Don't mind cloning, you need to install windows to the SSD for it to work.

Comment: @LPChip I did succeed in installing the OS. And as I said, I can turn it on by booting to the USB but not pressing any key. I'm trying to install Windows 7 now after I deleted the partition and created a new one on a working system instead of the installer.

Comment: I'm getting a "Setup was unable to create a new system partition..." error now.